# Wait for TextToSpeech onInit() initialization on Android

Tags: android, android-service, text-to-speech

I am writing a text-to-speech android application. I am refactoring the code and trying to separate TextToSpeech class from an activity to a service so the UI can be updated without blocking, while the audio is playing in the background. However I am not able to wait for the TTS engine to initialize.

When I use

```
while(isInit==false)
     Thread.sleep(1000);
```

the service never calls the onServiceConnected method.

If anybody knows how to wait for initialization of the TTS engine to complete, and avoid blocking the UI for too long (which causes the application to crash), help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my service

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MyTTSService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "Class-MyTTSService";
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private boolean isInit = false;
    private final IBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating TTS Service");
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        this.tts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);
        this.tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(utteranceProgressListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "TTS Service Created");

        // why is this blocking everything?
        while(!isInitComplete()){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isInitComplete(){
        return isInit;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void waitToFinishSpeaking() {
        while (tts.isSpeaking()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void speak(String text, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Speak" + text);
        appCompatActivity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        } else {
            String utteranceId=this.hashCode() + "";
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
        }
    }

    private UtteranceProgressListener utteranceProgressListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to synthesize sample text");
        }
    };

    private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener onInitListener =  new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                } else {
                    //init success
                    isInit = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "TTS Initialized.");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Binding TTS Service");
        return myBinder;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        MyTTSService getService() {
            return MyTTSService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is my activity

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Class-ReaderActivity";
    EditText textBox;
    ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyTTSService tts;
    boolean isBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.readerTextArea);
        Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
        Bundle extrasBundle = intentExtras.getExtras();
        sentences = extrasBundle.getStringArrayList("sentences");
        textBox.setText(sentences.toString(), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
        textBox.setKeyListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTTSService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting to bind to service");
    }

    public void readSentences(){
        for(String sentence : sentences){
            Log.d(TAG +"Sencence", sentence);
            //updateUI(sentence);
            tts.speak(sentence, this);
            tts.waitToFinishSpeaking();
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MyTTSService.MyBinder binder = (MyTTSService.MyBinder) service;
            tts = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
            readSentences();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            isBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You are blocking `onCreate` in the Service with the loop. `onInit' is asynchronous, and you should not 'wait' for it to complete, rather you should 'react' once it has completed in your listener. You can send confirmation of this event via the service connection.

Comment: @brandall is onServiceConnected not called automatically when onBind is completed?

Comment: Have a read up on locally bound services. There are plenty of examples showing how to communicate to and from them with different callbacks you define.

Comment: @brandall if I remove the wait loop, onServiceConnected method is called and all the sentences are processed instantly (with no audio) before the TTS module is initialised

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Remove the existing wait loop from MyTTSService.onCreate().

Place the following at the end of the onServiceConnected method

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run(){
          readSentences();
     }
}).start();
```

Then add a method to MyTTSService

```
public boolean isInit(){
     return isInit;
}
```

In some circumstances the tts module may need to be reinitialised. Add the following to TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.OnInit in the cases where initialisation is unsuccessful.

```
isInit = false;
```

Then finally add the following to the readsentences method

```
while(!tts.isInit()){
     try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
     }
}
tts.speak(sentence, this);
```

With these changes the TTS module initialises, audio works, the Activity loads and the UI can be refreshed while audio is playing.

This should finally put the issue (which has been asked several times but never resolved) to bed for good.

Comment: This may work for now, but what will happen when you want to read dynamic content? You need a service connection that sends the utterances and receives callbacks. This is very complex - take a look at my implementation https://github.com/brandall76/Saiy-PS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ai/saiy/android/service/SelfAware.java#L203 Also, what happens if the initialisation of the TTS object continuously fails? You'll be stuck in an endless loop.